# Chrome extension: jQuery callback on options page runs before DOM loads

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have developed my first Chrome extension that generates mock data on the fly and inserting it into form elements. I am developing an options page for it. I have a callback to populate form elements on the option page. The callback runs when I reload the extension, and there is nothing in the DOM for jQuery to query. What is going on, and how do I modify my code so that it will run the options callback once the options DOM is rendered?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Dummy Data",
"author": "Jay Bienvenu",
"description": "Insert dummy data into form elements with a few clicks.",
"version": "3.8",

"permissions": ["activeTab","contextMenus","downloads"],
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js","lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "moment.js","q.js",
    "data.js",
    "english.js","german.js","greek.js","japanese.js","spanish.js",
    "core.js","script.js","options.js"
  ]
},
"options_page": "options.html"
}
```

**options.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Dummy Data: Options</title>
<link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Options for Dummy Data</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="language">Language</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="languages"></select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**options.js**

```
$(function() {

  $languages = $("#languages");

  $("#languages option").remove();

  $languages.change(function() {
    var languageName = $(this).val();
    _language = languageName;
    localStorage["language"] = languageName;
  });

  for (var l in _languages) {
    $languages.append("<option>"+l+"</option>");
  }

});
```

Comment: _"All of the code for this question, including the incomplete options page, is in the repository linked above."_ This is not acceptable for Stack Oveflow; the URL may go dead or change, and it prevents efficient indexing of your question. Remember: by asking here, you're creating Q&A for others to use, not just to help you. Please boil down your code to only relevant parts and post them here. See also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe jQuery 1.11 doesn't support `$(function() {})` properly. Simply move all `<script>` elements before the closing `</body>` tag and don't use the wrapper. If this is the case we have a duplicate question for that.

Comment: Edited per Xan's request.

Comment: At this point, I can only recommend you to try debugging this with [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). I don't see (even after looking at your full code) how `_languages` are really initialized, and I suspect your code just errors out in `core.js`. So you haven't included a complete example yet.

Comment: I gave you the complete code. You told me it wasn't acceptable.

The tutorial isn't helpful. I've already traced and stepped through the code in the Developer Tools. I set a breakpoint in options.js. It ran when I loaded the extension. It did NOT run when I opened the options page.